# ogr2ogr - gpx to PostGIS has wrong timezone adjustment

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

A gpx track point:

```
  <trkpt lat="52.321775959804654" lon="-72.647269548848271">
    <time>2014-10-01T16:07:19Z</time>
  </trkpt>
```

is imported with ogrogr in my PostGIS database with the following result:

```
            time          |                 st_astext
  ------------------------+-------------------------------------------
  2014-10-01 12:07:19-04 | POINT(-72.6472695488483 52.3217759598047)
```

The trouble is I am at -5 UTC (not -04) and my computer is set as such as can be seen here:

```
DB=> SELECT NOW();
        now
----------------------------
 2014-11-24 23:39:40.629-05
```

Why does this happens and how I should go about correcting this?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my! I just realized we were in Eastern Daylight Saving time when the position was taken so that is the correct result.